# Amazon EC2 Instance Stores being used for user http session files

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage, session-variables, grails-2.0

I have about 160GB of storage area on ec2 instance. Since this storage is temporary, Can I use it for session variable files ? Each time a user log-in, I create the session file for him on the instance storage and if the server is rebooted, when they visit the website, they can log-in again as if the session has been expired. Any thought or suggestion on that ? I'm using Grails building my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to Amazon documentation all data on this storage is deleted after reboot.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

If you want your users stay logged-in after rebooting the server, you have to select instance store volumes.

Comment: So If I don't mind them log back in, I can leave the session files there on instance store ? It also mentions that the instance store is pretty fast in comparison to EBS.

Comment: Yes, if it is not an issue if users must re-login, then you can use this storage for session files. We use this devise for files cache in a "bigdata" project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the instance store for temporary storage. This is probably the best way to do use it.

With session storage however, it will be much faster to use something like memcached than to read and write files to disk.

Comment: I have limited RAM/Memory though, so I didn't want memcached takes up my memory. My grail has a caching plugin that is taking up some space as well, and I think since my application isn't a multi-cluster one, memcached might be too soon to use. thanks for the suggestion though :)